# "graph-for-funcs.sc" script compilation error

Tags: scala, joern

I am trying to reproduce the `devign` experiment. When `joern` is updated, some error messages appear in the `graph-for-funcs.sc` script that parses the bin file into JSON. I modified some, and there are still some errors as shown in the figure below. Did you encounter similar errors and how did you solve them?

### graph-for-funcs.sc

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}

import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.expressions.generalizations.CfgNode
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.EdgeTypes
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.NodeTypes
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes
import io.shiftleft.dataflowengineoss.language._
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language._
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.expressions.Call
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.structure.Local
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes.MethodParameterIn

import overflowdb._
import overflowdb.traversal._

final case class GraphForFuncsFunction(function: String,
                                       file: String,
                                       id: String,
                                       AST: List[nodes.AstNode],
                                       CFG: List[nodes.AstNode],
                                       PDG: List[nodes.AstNode])
final case class GraphForFuncsResult(functions: List[GraphForFuncsFunction])

implicit val encodeEdge: Encoder[Edge] =
  (edge: Edge) =>
    Json.obj(
      ("id", Json.fromString(edge.toString)),
      ("in", Json.fromString(edge.inNode.toString)),
      ("out", Json.fromString(edge.outNode.toString))
    )

implicit val encodeNode: Encoder[nodes.AstNode] =
  (node: nodes.AstNode) =>
    Json.obj(
      ("id", Json.fromString(node.toString)),
      ("edges",
        Json.fromValues((node.inE("AST", "CFG").l ++ node.outE("AST", "CFG").l).map(_.asJson))),
      ("properties", Json.fromValues(node.propertyMap.asScala.toList.map { case (key, value) =>
        Json.obj(
          ("key", Json.fromString(key)),
          ("value", Json.fromString(value.toString))
        )
      }))
    )

implicit val encodeFuncFunction: Encoder[GraphForFuncsFunction] = deriveEncoder
implicit val encodeFuncResult: Encoder[GraphForFuncsResult] = deriveEncoder

@main def main(): Json = {
  GraphForFuncsResult(
    cpg.method.map { method =>
      val methodName = method.fullName
      val methodId = method.toString
      val methodFile = method.location.filename

      val astChildren = method.astMinusRoot.l
      val cfgChildren = method.out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS).asScala.collect { case node: nodes.CfgNode => node }.toList

      val local = new NodeSteps(
        method
          .out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS)
          .hasLabel(NodeTypes.BLOCK)
          .out(EdgeTypes.AST)
          .hasLabel(NodeTypes.LOCAL)
          .cast[nodes.Local])
      val sink = local.evalType(".*").referencingIdentifiers.dedup
      val source = new NodeSteps(method.out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS).hasLabel(NodeTypes.CALL).cast[nodes.Call]).nameNot("<operator>.*").dedup

      val pdgChildren = sink
        .reachableByFlows(source)
        .l
        .flatMap { path =>
          path.elements
            .map {
              case trackingPoint @ (_: MethodParameterIn) => trackingPoint.start.method.head
              case trackingPoint                          => trackingPoint.cfgNode
            }
        }
        .filter(_.toString != methodId)

      GraphForFuncsFunction(methodName, methodFile, methodId, astChildren, cfgChildren, pdgChildren.distinct)
    }.l
  ).asJson
}
```

---

### error

```
graph-for-funcs.sc:92: value evalType is not a member of io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.NodeSteps[io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes.Local]
      val sink = local.evalType(".*").referencingIdentifiers.dedup
                       ^
graph-for-funcs.sc:93: value nameNot is not a member of io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.NodeSteps[io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes.Call]
      val source = new NodeSteps(method.out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS).hasLabel(NodeTypes.CALL).cast[nodes.Call]).nameNot("<operator>.*").dedup
                                                                                                           ^
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation Failed
  io.shiftleft.console.scripting.AmmoniteExecutor.$anonfun$runScript$7(AmmoniteExecutor.scala:50)
  cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.liftedTree3$1(IORunLoop.scala:229)
  cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.step(IORunLoop.scala:229)
  cats.effect.IO.unsafeRunTimed(IO.scala:320)
  cats.effect.IO.unsafeRunSync(IO.scala:239)
  io.shiftleft.console.scripting.ScriptManager.runScript(ScriptManager.scala:130)
  io.shiftleft.console.scripting.ScriptManager$CpgScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptManager.scala:64)
  io.shiftleft.console.scripting.ScriptManager$CpgScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptManager.scala:54)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd8$.<clinit>(cmd8.sc:1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to post as little code as possible and when doing so, also include what command you ran as well as what versions of which dependencies were present and how. Otherwise it is very difficult to guess what might be going on here :)